# I'm trying to make a click counter using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'somedb';
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);
if (isset($_POST['abc'])){
    $date_today = date('Y-m-d');
    $somecount=("INSERT INTO sometable (today,somecount) VALUES ('".$date_today."', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE somecount=somecount+1");
    mysqli_query($conn, $somecount);
}

?>

<form method="post" action="some.php">
    <input type="submit" name="abc">
</form>
```

I've tried this code. Someone please help me out to count the click made by the user on a button or submit input tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, what is the problem you currently facing, it is not counting?

Comment: Your code above seems to have what you already want.

Comment: Yeah it does not count the clicks!

Comment: Is `today` column unique in database?

Comment: today column is a PRIMARY KEY in my db

Comment: @SarathDev Please show us your table structure

Answer (score 0):

Just update this line:
From

```
$somecount=("INSERT INTO sometable (today,somecount) VALUES ('".$date_today."', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE somecount=somecount+1");
```

to

```
$somecount=("INSERT INTO sometable (today,somecount) VALUES ('".$date_today."', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE somecount=somecount+1");
```

also, to make sure you are not redirecting to another page that the current page itself do the below code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="abc">
</form>
```

doing so will make sure that you will submit to the same page.

Comment: it would be helpful to state what you have changed and why.

Comment: Just now I tried your suggestion. But unfortunately no. Still I get no changes in my db.

Comment: @RayA I redirected it to the same page and tried as u said. Still I got no solution. Need help!!!!!

Comment: do not panic, will get you to have your code working, can you share with us the table structure to which you want to save the counts?

Comment: @RayA. There are two fields in my table "sometable". Field1: today ,Type: date , NULL: NO, Key: PRIMARY, Default: NULL. Field2: somecount , Type: int(11), NULL: NO.

Comment: can you confirm that you can connect to DB?
add this code to make sure you are connected `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} `

Comment: yeah! I've checked it. It connects to the DB perfectly.  ;_;

Comment: hmm, then try this line: `$somecount="INSERT INTO sometable (today,somecount) VALUES ('".$date_today."', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE somecount=somecount+1";` I removed the brackets

Comment: still. i get no changes in the value in db! is there any problem with my machine? But i tried this same code on my friend's machine. it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** and instead use a little bit different logic:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'somedb';
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);
if (isset($_POST['abc'])){
    $date_today = date('Y-m-d');
    $selectStatement = "SELECT somecount FROM sometable WHERE today = '".$date_today."'";
    $selectResult = mysqli_query($conn, $selectStatemnt);
    $finalStatement = "";
    if($selectResult){
        $finalStatement = "UPDATE sometable SET somecount = somecount + 1 WHERE today = '".$date_today."'";
    }
    else{
        $finalStatement = "INSERT INTO sometable (today,somecount) VALUES ('".$date_today."', 1)";
    }
    mysqli_query($conn, $finalStatement);
}

?>

<form method="post" action="some.php">
    <input type="submit" name="abc">
</form>
```

Here we first check if the row for **today** already exists in the table. **If** so simply increment it **else** create a row and set the **count** value to one.

Comment: your approach is good, but it will consume more time executing, imagine he has 100 users at the same time, it will be a loop of select, update, insert

Comment: @RayA I think with the given information from the OP this is the only approach that will work. I couldn't find any issues in his code. The only thing that came to mind is maybe the problem is in what SQL/NoSQL he is using.

Comment: let's wait to see the table structure then we can figure it out.

Comment: THIS IS MY TABLE STRUCTURE
today                     DATE           PRIMARY KEY
somecount            INT(11)

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov Yeah, I tried your code. Didn't work, I found no value changes in the table of my database.